# Remote Access from home to office, and office to home

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp

How can I use Remote Access from my home to my office, and from my office to my home?

I am using Windows XP in the office and Windows 7 at home.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the guide on [this](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/internet/10208/how-to-set-up-Windows-XP-remote-access/). Note, that if you do not have Windows XP Professional, then you have to download it at the link provided on the page.

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as the answer (click the check to make it green). If it does not, please comment to say what is missing. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Of course,  you can configure a VPN or open a port in your firewall...

But you might want to consider [TeamViewer](http://www.teamviewer.com/en/index.aspx); free for home use, not for commercial.

Or [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/); basic services are free.